# crontab logs not being created/emailed

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am working on a project for one of my classes using crontab. However, I cannot seem to get the log to be created. It is supposed to execute this file every minute for 5 minutes. My cron is written as this:

`MAILTO=email@gmail.com`

`1,2,3,4,5 * * * * test.py >> /docs/cron.log`

After saving the crontab, I get the message:
`crontab: installing new crontab`

Additionally, I do not see what I'm looking for in syslog.

Am I missing something here? Maybe I'm writing the syntax completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ crontab -e
*/5 * * * * python3 /yourAbsolutePath/test.py >> ~/docs/cron.log 2>&1
```

Reference:
the https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/crontab-log/
and https://crontab.guru/